# How to use Jquery ligtslider in angular 11

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#autoWidth').lightSlider({
        autoWidth:true,
        loop:true,
        onSliderLoad: function() {
            $('#autoWidth').removeClass('cS-hidden');
        } 
    });  
  });
```

this is code I need to use it on angular
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html

Comment: Not the same but might help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-light-carousel?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Please do not mix JQuery and Angular.  It is like crossing the streams and a bad idea.  There should be Angular based UI Libs, such as ng-bootstrap or ng material that have sliders.